# How to find the random index in an array?

Tags: java, arrays

1. Create 8 randomly generated integer values between 1 to 50. DONE
2. Display the series of values on screen. DONE
3. Users has to enter value. Find index & display.
4. if value cannot be found, display -none.

Comment: how about code and try? if google can't help you solve this, you should try to up your google skills

Comment: This wouldn't happen to be homework, would it?

Comment: @Stultuske thanks for the tip. Got the first 2 by googling.

Comment: @Henrik correct but my major is in networking(part time). Java is new for me yet it's fun but can't cope up in a very short time plus juggling with work & play.

Comment: @DhaneshR seeing as the third and fourth are easier than the first, I'm pretty sure you'll figure it out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is pretty easy. As you already completed step 1 and 2 you just have to ask the user for an input, search your array and output the index, if the input matches a value in the array.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    Random random = new Random(); 
    int[] numbers = new int[8];

    for(int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
        numbers[i] = random.nextInt(50) + 1;
        System.out.print(numbers[i] + ", ");
    }

    System.out.print("\nInput value: ");
    int input = scanner.nextInt();
    boolean found = false;

    for(int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
        if(input == numbers[i]) {
            System.out.println("Index: " + i);
            found = true;
        }
    }

    if(!found) {
        System.out.println("none");
    }
}
```